# Как проверить, что введена буква, а не число?

Tags: python

Решил изучить питон, скачал курс. Я совсем прям новичек, изучаю 3 день. Там было такое задание:

1. Попросите пользователя ввести 2 числа.
2. Сохраните в переменную результат деления первого числа на второе при условии, что делитель не равен 0. Если делитель равен 0, то сохранить в переменную строку: «бесконечность».
3. Вывести пользователю ответ в таком виде: «ЧИСЛО_1 / ЧИСЛО_2 = ОТВЕТ».
   Примечание: разумеется, вместо «ЧИСЛО_1», «ЧИСЛО_2» и «ОТВЕТ» должны быть подставлены соответствующие переменные.

Видел тут 2 года назад уже задавали тот же вопрос, решения в теме я так и не нашел. Весь вечер ломал голову над 3 пунктом задания (наверно потому что занимался почти целый день) но так и не смог решить, а с утра проснулся, позавтракал сел и сразу же понял как выполнить данную задачу. Мне так же стало интересно, как добавить в этот код следущее "if" - если пользователь вводит букву а не число - вывести принт "Можно вводить только числа"

```
num1 = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
num2 = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
if num2 != 0:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
else:
    print("Бесконечность")
```

Answer (score 4):

Давайте напишем функцию которая печатает прилашение и читает строку. Если в строке вещественное число, функция его возвращает. Если нет, функция печатает сообщение об ошибке и начинает всё с начала. Блок  `try/except` проверяет ввод самым непосредственным образом: пытается перевести строку в число.

```
def inputFloat(prompt=None):
    while True:
        s = input(prompt)
        try:
            return float(s)
        except ValueError:
            print('Ошибка. Ожидалось вещественное число.')


f = inputFloat('Введите число: ')
print('Вы ввели', f)
```

> ```
> $ python input-float.py 
> Введите число: 12ab
> Ошибка. Ожидалось вещественное число.
> Введите число: ab12
> Ошибка. Ожидалось вещественное число.
> Введите число: 123
> Вы ввели 123.0
>
> $ python input-float.py 
> Введите число: 1e10
> Вы ввели 10000000000.0
> ```

Answer (score 3):

В условие для оператора `if` можно подставить результат метода [`isnumeric`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isnumeric#str.isnumeric). Данный метод вернёт `True`, если строка состоит только из числовых символов.

Но добавлять такую проверку нужно до преобразования строки в число, иначе возникнет исключение `ValueError`.

***Пример:***

```py
num1 = input('Введите первое число: ')

if num1.isnumeric():
    num1 = float(num1)
else:
    print('Можно вводить только числа')
```

---

Вместо проверки через условие можно использовать обработку исключений. Это куда более надёжный вариант:

```py
try:
    num1 = float(input('Введите первое число: '))

except ValueError:
    print('Недопустимый ввод')
```

Comment: Примерно понял, скажите можно ли добавить данную проверку через цикл while? что бы при вводе любого символа кроме числа, скрипт возвращал на строку "Введите первое число" ?

Comment: @ЭмТри Конечно можно, сейчас опубликую.

Comment: Решение неверное.

Comment: @vlados155, в ответе два варианта решения, стоит уточнять, про какой вариант вы говорите. Второй вариант вполне работоспособный (работает не только с целыми числами), и намного проще предложенного вами.

Comment: Новички мало знают про обработку исключений, поэтому я написал без неё, говорил я про первый вариант, работающий только с целыми числами.

Comment: @vlados155 `Новички мало знают про обработку исключений` - ну я не думаю, что стоит обобщать, к тому же, если не знают, то почему бы не изучить. В целом, в данном случае наиболее удобно как раз использовать обработку ошибки через исключения, а не навешивать какой-то сложный разбор числа на части поверх простого ввода.

Comment: @insolor Согласен, но я сам про обработку исключений мало знаю) думаю, хороший повод изучить.

Answer (score 3):

Я сократил Ваш код и добавил проверку:

```
num1='a'
num2='a'
while not num2.isdigit() and not num1.isdigit(): num1=input('Введите число 1: '); num2=input('Введите число 2: ')
num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)
print(num1, "/", num2, "=", num1 / num2 if num2 != 0 else "Бесконечность")
```

Но можно оставить Ваш код:

```
num1='a'
num2='a'
while not num2.isdigit() and not num1.isdigit(): num1=input('Введите число 1: '); num2=input('Введите число 2: ')
num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)
if num2 != 0:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
else:
    print("Бесконечность")
```

Comment: этот код будет работать только с целыми числами, так как не даст ввести нецелое число

Answer (score 2):

> скажите можно ли добавить данную проверку через цикл while? что бы при вводе любого символа кроме числа, скрипт возвращал на строку "Введите первое число" ?

Будет работать только такой код, метод `isnumeric()` не распознаёт разделитель (точку) и возвращает False.

Примерно так:

```
def is_valid(n: list):
    if len(n) == 2:  # Если в числе одна точка
        for i in n:
            if not i.isdigit():
                return False
            return True
    else:
        return False
while True:
    num1 = input()
    num2 = input()
    nums1 = num1.split('.')  # создаём список, в котором хранится целая и дробная части числа (при вводе "2.222" в список имеет вид: ['2', '222']
    nums2 = num2.split('.')
    if is_valid(nums1) and is_valid(nums2):
        num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)
        break  # прерываем бесконечный цикл, если всё в порядке
    else:
        print('Вы можете ввести только числа!')  # требуем от пользователя ввести числа
if num2 != 0:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
else:
    print("Бесконечность")
```

Функционал кода предусматривает проверку введённых значений на соответствие типу `int`; программа абсолютно работоспособна.

Comment: Спасибо. В принципе разобрался, я только начал осваивать язык. т.е, это первый язык который я решил освоить основательно. И по урокам пока ещё не дошел до операторов типа 'def' 'for' 'return' и тд. Пока только в уроках начали проходить циклы 'if' и 'while' Но раньше имел опыт в написании макросов типа "Easy UO" для Ultima Online. Там похожий на питон язык. Но в целом спасибо, Вы помогли мне освежить память и расширить кругозор.

Comment: код выдает ошибку если введена строка с несколькими точками ('5.2.3')

Comment: @ЭмТри def - это функция (на будущее), у неё есть инструкция return, пока не углубляйтесь в это. Можно обойтись и без функций, но код будет больше. После того как изучите списки и ещё пару типов данных, а также функции, сможете написать такой же код)

Comment: @SergFSM Он и не должен работать, в числе же одна точка, прочитайте, про функционал программы.

Comment: @vlados155 В числе одна точка, но сколько их будет в строке неизвестно. В принципе это легко поправить если добавить в вашу функцию проверку на длину списка, и если она больше 2 возвращать False.

Comment: Вообще верное замечание, чтобы исключить вызов ошибки, следует добавить такую проверку.

Answer (score 1):

проверку с циклом можно еще сделать такими способами:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Введите первое число: "))
        num2 = float(input("Введите второе число: "))
        break
    except:
        print('Ошибка ввода')
if num2 != 0:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
else:
    print("Бесконечность")
```

или

```
while True:
    num1 = input("Введите первое число: ")
    num2 = input("Введите второе число: ")
    if num1.replace('.','',1).isdigit() and num2.replace('.','',1).isdigit(): 
        num1, num2 = float(num1), float(num2)
        break
    else: 
        print('Ошибка ввода')
if num2 != 0:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
else:
    print("Бесконечность")
```

Comment: Первое решение мне очень понравилось коротко и ясно. Я хочу стремится к такому же стилю написания кода - краткость сестра таланта.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Введите первое число:"))
        break
    except:
        print("Можно вводить только числа")
while True:
    try:
        num2 = float(input("Введите второе число:"))
        if num2 == 0:
            print("Нельзя делить на ноль")
        break
    except:
        print("Можно вводить только числа")
if num2 != 0:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
```

Я решил немного изменить ваш вариант, который мне понравился, изменил так, чтобы проверка на число была при каждом введении. Так же хотел что бы при проверке второго числа, в случае если пользователь ввёл `0`, скрипт вернул его к вводу второго числа с `print("нельзя делить на ноль")`. Тогда и в последней части скрипта отпадёт надобность задавать условие if на проверку неравенства нулю и можно будет сразу вывести `print(x = num1 / num2)`, верно?

Comment: Слишком долгое решение. Большой код зачем?

Comment: к тому же если в для второго числа введу ноль, то программа не даст мне ввести второе число еще раз и завершится. Надобность в условии if последней части скрипта, разумеется, отпала, но зачем же все-таки это условие там осталось?

Comment: В идеале конечно я стремлюсь писать код как можно короче, но на данном этапе нет картины в голове как это реализовать технически :) условие if в конце осталось потому как изначальная задача требует не делить на ноль, а вывести принт о невозможности деления на ноль.

Answer (score 0):

Единственный вариант  который выполняет задачу вместо деления на 0 выводить принт о невозможности данной операции до которого я смог додуматься - вот такой:

```
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Введите первое число:"))
        break
    except:
        print("Можно вводить только числа")
while True:
    try:
        num2 = float(input("Введите второе число:"))
        break
    except:
        print("Можно вводить только числа")
if num2 == 0:
    print("Нельзя делить на ноль")
else:
    x = num1 / num2
    print(num1, "/", num2, "=", x)
```

Конечно код немного длиннее, но за то, при вводе первого числа отличного от `float` он не дает ввести второе значение (что уже помоему разумению лишено смысла, поскольку в первом значении уже введено неверное значение), а сразу сообщает п-лю о неверном вводе.

Comment: Но в этом решении скрипт завершается без возможности вернуть пользователя к вводу 2 значения с принтом "Нельзя делить на ноль"

Answer (score 0):

Условие:

1. Попросите пользователя ввести 2 числа.
2. Сохраните в переменную результат деления первого числа на второе при условии, что делитель не равен 0. Если делитель равен 0, то сохранить в переменную строку: «бесконечность».
3. Вывести пользователю ответ в таком виде: «ЧИСЛО_1 / ЧИСЛО_2 = ОТВЕТ».
   Примечание: разумеется, вместо «ЧИСЛО_1», «ЧИСЛО_2» и «ОТВЕТ» должны быть подставлены соответствующие переменные.

Решение:

```
x1=float(input('vvedite 1 chislo '))

x2=float(input('vvedite 2 chislo '))

if x2 == 0:

    x3 = 'besconechnost'
else:

    x3=x1/x2  
print (x1,'/',x2, '=',x3)
```